# Range slide not going to max value when there is steps also

Tags: html, angular

I am setting up range slider in my angular project. The all values for range slider is coming from api.Api response for slider is looking like this.

```
[{
  toolValue: { defaultvalue: 120,
               min: 30,
               max: 120,
               step: 30 }
}]
```

I am setting up these values in range slider and the slider is working but when step value is **30** or any other then the slider is not going to max position, instead of it is setting up at position 90. But when the steps are **0.1**, that time slider is set to max position . I don't know what wrong with steps.

Html code:

```
<input type="range" class="slider" [value]="item.toolValue.defaultvalue" [min]="item.toolValue.min" [max]="item.toolValue.max" [step]="item.toolValue.step"  id="rangeslider{{index}}" (mouseup)="onMouseupRangeslider($event.target.value,item,index)">
```

Please let me know how to [image: Slider image]

As you can see in the upper image, From API in both slider the default value is coming **100** and **120**. In first slider steps are **0.1**, so that it's going to max position but in the second slider, steps are 30 so that the slider is not going to max position, instead of it is stopped at **90**. Please help me with this issue. Thank you
The api response for slider values are as per below.

```
[{
cols: 12
id: "dvetool0"
rows: 3
toolValue: {defaultvalue: 100, max: 100, min: 0, step: 0.1}
type: "rangeslider"
x: 0
y: 0 }, 
{
cols: 11
id: "dvetool1"
rows: 3
toolValue: {defaultvalue: 120, max: 120, min: 30, step: 30}
type: "rangeslider"
x: 0
y: 4 }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Answer:
To follow up after your clarification, I think your problem is the use of the [value] DOM property here. Instead, try tracking the value with ngModel instead.

Replace `[value]="default"` with `[(ngModel)]="inputValue"` and create the `inputValue` variable in your component.ts

Here's a working stackblitz as an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szdxyn

By the way, the reason you were seeing 90 is because the browser calculates a a default value using rangeElem.min + (rangeElem.max - rangeElem.min)/2. See the MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#Value

Comment: ,sorry I did mistaked in showing JSON array in question.Default value will be 120 as per in second slider of image.I ediited my question

Comment: My default values are [30,60,90,120] ,if steps are 30

Comment: If it's not working with legal values of min, max, and default, then you need to show your onMouseupRangeslider() code, because the problem is probably its implementation

Comment: The values for slider is coming from api directly.Let me show you the api response.

Comment: I added response of api in question pls check it.

Comment: Thank you keenan for you demo but in your demo also as you can see ,default value you set is 120 but still its not going to 120 position.I tried [value] = "inputValue " in your code ,that time slider is going to 90 position ,not 120

Comment: Sorry, I'm little tired and didn't use the banana-box syntax correctly. Check it again, should be working now.